# Groovy: Convert Array to JSon

Tags: json, grails, groovy

Am new to Groovy and am having trouble converting an array to JSON. The JSON computed should have all the values from my array list, but it is storing only the last one. Here is the code:

```
def arraylist = [["0",2],["1",8],["2",6],["3",8],["4",3]]

def arraysize = arraylist.size()

def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
 builder ({
       cols([
                {
                    "id" "hours"
                    "label" "Hours"
                    "type" "string"
                },
                {
                    "id" "visitor"
                    "label" "Visitors"
                    "type" "number"
                }
           ])

         rows([
                {
                        for( i in 0..< arraysize )
                        {
                        c([
                             {
                                 "v" arraylist[i][0]
                             },
                             {
                                 "v" arraylist[i][1]
                             }
                         ])
                        }//for

                }
           ])
})

println builder.toPrettyString()
```

Can try running the code here:
http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/

Expected output is here:

```
{
"cols": [
    {
        "id": "hours",
        "label": "Hours",
        "type": "string"
    },
    {
        "id": "visitor",
        "label": "Visitors",
        "type": "number"
    }
],
"rows": [
    {
        "c": [
            {
                "v": "0"
            },
            {
                "v": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "c": [
            {
                "v": "1"
            },
            {
                "v": 8
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "c": [
            {
                "v": "2"
            },
            {
                "v": 6
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "c": [
            {
                "v": "3"
            },
            {
                "v": 8
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "c": [
            {
                "v": "4"
            },
            {
                "v": 3
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `render arraylist as JSON` in your controller? Here's some [example](http://manbuildswebsite.com/2010/01/29/rendering-json-using-grails-part-1-collections-testing-and-the-jsonbuilder/)

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you're expecting?  Your code is confusing...

Comment: Have edited the question - @tim_yates

Comment: @will thanks... Posted a possible solution, let me know if any of it needs explaining :-)

Comment: Thanks Tim...Brilliant! Saved the day for me! Sorry for the late response :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this seems to give the result you wanted:

```
def arraylist = [["0",2],["1",8],["2",6],["3",8],["4",3]]

def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
builder {
  cols( [
    [ id: "hours",   label: "Hours",    type: "string" ],
    [ id: "visitor", label: "Visitors", type: "number" ] ] )

  rows( arraylist.collect { pair -> [ c: pair.collect { item -> [ v: item ] } ] } )
}

println builder.toPrettyString()
```