# Render result as real JSON, not arraylist

Tags: groovy

I have some trouble in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739152/groovy-convert-array-to-json), but his problem is quite hard for me to understand the jsonbuilder... Below I have my array rendering as JSON using `createCriteria`.

```
render result as JSON
//output
[[1,"a"],[1,"b"],[1,"c"],[1,"d"],[2,"e"]]
```

How can transform it to json like this?

```
[{"quantity":1,"week":"a"},{"quantity":1,"week":"b"},{"quantity":2,"week":"c"}]
```

Comment: how do you build the result?  if you would have a map with that data in the first place the render as json would work.  the result would have to be a list of maps with the keys `quantity` and `week`.

Comment: Hmm... I m using createCriteria().list

Comment: so it's just `def result = SomeModel.createCriteria.list()`?

Comment: And projections, `count("id") groupProperty("week")`

Comment: you can add a `resultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)` in the closure for the criteria to get a list of maps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result.collect { [quantity: it[0], week:it[1]]} as JSON
```

Comment: Where does `JSON` come from? Grails?

Answer (score 0):

```
class JsonTest {    

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        def jsonSlurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
        def data = [[1,"a"],[1,"b"],[1,"c"],[1,"d"],[2,"e"]]
        List<JsonObject> array = new ArrayList<JsonObject>()
        data.each{quantity,week -> array.add(new JsonObject(quantity, week))}
        println new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(array).toPrettyString()
    }  
}

class JsonObject {

    Integer quantity
    String week

    public JsonObject(Integer quantity, String week) {
        this.quantity = quantity
        this.week = week
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't knew, that groovy can destructure iterators.  but with grails it's easier to do `render [[1,"a"],[1,"b"],[1,"c"],[1,"d"],[2,"e"]].collect{q,w -> [quantity: q, week: w]} as JSON`